# asyncio or threads for long running background tasks

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio

I'm a relative python noob so apologies if this is a stupid question, but what is the best approach for handling long-running background jobs? So the basic premise of what I'm trying to achieve

- Web app running FastAPI handles all user "interaction"
- Background task responsible for streaming data from a third party API
- Background task responsible for other activities

The web app side of things is fine, but where I'm running into no end of confusion is the background jobs. Logically in my head, the background workers are isolated jobs essentially so they run in their own threads and do whatever they need to do. Any kind of communication would happen through queues but really this would just be to send simple instructions (like "start streaming X data", or "stop streaming Y data").

Obviously whilst developing this I came across asyncio which seems to be touted as having advantages to threads in a number of ways, but I can't get my head around how it would work in this situation. I think I've got it running as a background job (using `create_task` and then waiting for them with `asyncio.wait([t1, t2...])`) which seems to work, but then I run into the next issue - the library I'm using for streaming internally uses asyncio. When I try to start the streaming, I get an error about being unable to start asyncio in an existing asyncio loop which makes sense, but then I have no idea how to make this work. I've seen references to using libraries like the nested asyncio lib, but this all feels like hacky-ish workarounds just to make something work which would've been much simpler in a thread.

How would you tackle this? Just use threads, or am I overlooking something with asyncio and doing something stupid?

Comment: What does the library's documentation say about using it while running other asyncio tasks?  If the library really does prevent you from running other asyncio tasks, you should get a different library.

Comment: The relevant part for me was _"background workers are isolated jobs..."_. Assuming these activities are I/O bound, I would go with threads. If they are CPU bound, separate processes will be the only way to go (due to the GIL). If they were logically more intertwined with your main application, the asyncio approach might have been more interesting.

Comment: @PaulCornelius I looked at its internals and I could call a different method to use the existing asyncio loop so not too worried about the lib itself

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg Yeah they're primarily IO bound. It's streaming data feeds from another service, and then passing it on somewhere else essentially. To me threads made more sense as well but wasn't sure being new to python. If I needed to then communicate with that thead to add new items to stream, what's the best way if it's currently busy? Don't queues block waiting on a message so that would block the thread doing other things?